# How to convert MOV (with Alpha) to MP4 (with ALpha) - using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, quicktime, transparency, webm

I am trying to convert a `MOV` (with alpha channel) to `WebM` and `Mp4` (with Alpha channel) using FFmpeg.
The WebM video is coming with the Alpha channel.
But the video is not supported in SAFARI Browser.

I found [this website](https://genies.com/) that has transparent videos in both formats (WebM & Mp4).
So it seems it is possible to have MOV and Mp4 with a transparent background.

How to convert MOV to Mp4 while preserving the alpha channel using FFmpeg?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. It [seems](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/23894) that mp4 does not support alpha channel... Give it a look. BTW [edit] your post adding the command you used to convert from MOV I to WebM and that worked. It can be useful for others...

Comment: VP9 can support alpha, and you can put that in MP4, but I'm not sure what's what you want or if your browser will support it. Anyway, I can't give you an answer you can blindly copy and paste without seeing info about your input as provided by `ffmpeg -i input.mov`.